# Failed to execute adb.exe when trying to run Xamarin.UITest

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to setup a Xamarin UITest without any luck.

When I try to run 'all tests', I get the following error:

```
execute: C:\Users\Brandon\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices - exit code: 1
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
List of devices attached
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

ADB seems to be started just fine and the weird thing is that it seems to be using an adb version from another user, even though..

1) Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android is set to different path than the above-mentioned, for the Android SDK.

2) There is no system environment path variable that I can find for the above-referenced adb.exe path!

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Android Emulator version mismatch. Somehow Emulator got updated to the newer version:
[image]

After uninstalling Emulator, switching Feed to Microsoft instead of google and re-installing Emulator - error was gone and everything worked just fine.